# how to get the physical path to the ALAsset object

Tags: ios, url, filepath, alasset

Is there a way to turn the asset url returned by the following call to the physical path on the device?

```
NSURL *assetUrl = [_selectedAsset defaultRepresentation] url];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way. (And even if you had the path to file, your app could not read the file because of sandboxing.)

The only way to get the raw data of an asset is `getBytes:fromOffset:length:error:` in `ALAssetRepresentation`.